# Can procedure definitions be nested in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to nest procedure definitions in VBA so that the inner Sub has access to the outer Subs variables?

Something like...

```
Sub Outer()

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    Dim sel As Range
    Dim destCol As Variant
    Dim defCol As String
    Dim outerLoop As Boolean

    Sub Inner()

        ' Can I do this and get access to the outer variables in here?
        ' So that I can pass them to the Sub call in here and have that
        ' Sub call access the outer variables?

        dataSheet.Activate

        Set sel = dataSheet.ListObjects("ReqMarkerTable").ListColumns("Quantity").DataBodyRange
        destCol = GetInputBoxVal("Enter destination column:", "Column?", defCol)

        If destCol <> False Then
            Call DuplicateValsByQty(sheetName, destCol, sel)
            outerLoop = False
        End If

    End Sub

End Sub

Sub DuplicateValsByQty(sheetName As Variant, destCol As Variant, sel As Range)

    ' I want this Sub's call within the Inner Sub to have access to the outer variables.

End Sub
```

I want to avoid using global variables if possible.

Ultimately, I want to have several of these "Inner" Subs that process the same data in different ways.

Or is there some way that data in one Sub can be accessed from another? Something like dot notation in JS?

Perhaps I am looking at this all wrong?

Any help or direction provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NO. Such syntax is not allowed in VBA. Variable access from proc can be managed by using ByRef and ByVal in proc signature. accordingly.

Comment: @cyboashu Kind of like passing pointers in C?

Comment: I think that you might be looking for the `Private` variable declaration in the Module/Class header.

Comment: @GraemeR Will that create a kind of "global" variable?

Comment: Sort of, but only accessible to code in your Module or Class.

Comment: The late [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) had a good page on variable scopes.

Comment: Pull your `Inner` procedure out of the `Outer` procedure and rename it as `Sub Inner(MyOuterLoopRef as Boolean` (this will default to pass the variable [byRef](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)). Rename all the variable references in `Inner` to `MyOuterLoopRef`. Then call it from the `Outer` procedure by using `Inner outerloop`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you so much for the link to Chip Pearson. That site is a gargantuan collection of all things VBA! Much appreciated. Should keep me busy for months.